# Query to combine the result of two sub queries

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables with values as shown below

**tblIncome(Date,Income)**

- 12/02/2012  1000
- 14/02/2012  2000
- 10/03/2012  1500
- 05/03/2012  5000

**tblExpense(Date,Expense)**

- 05/02/2012  1200
- 10/02/2012  1000
- 15/03/2012  2000

**Expected result** is (Month,Income,Expense)

- February 3000 2200
- March    6500 2000

Comment: Do you plan on using this for more than one year?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions asks for a "calendar table". This term is known in the community and google will give many hits.

This is how mine looks

[image]

Complete the table (with a script preferably) for the other months required

Once that is in place you can run the query below in this script that will give you the results

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar](
    [MonthName] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [StartdateInclusive] [datetime] NULL,
    [EnddateExclusive] [datetime] NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([MonthName], [StartdateInclusive], [EnddateExclusive]) VALUES (N'February', CAST(0x00009FEA00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A00700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([MonthName], [StartdateInclusive], [EnddateExclusive]) VALUES (N'March', CAST(0x0000A00700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A02600000000 AS DateTime))


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblIncome](
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Income] [money] NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[tblIncome] ([Date], [Income]) VALUES (CAST(0x00009FF500000000 AS DateTime), 1000.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblIncome] ([Date], [Income]) VALUES (CAST(0x00009FF700000000 AS DateTime), 2000.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblIncome] ([Date], [Income]) VALUES (CAST(0x0000A01000000000 AS DateTime), 1500.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblIncome] ([Date], [Income]) VALUES (CAST(0x0000A00B00000000 AS DateTime), 5000.0000)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblExpense](
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Expense] [money] NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[tblExpense] ([Date], [Expense]) VALUES (CAST(0x00009FEE00000000 AS DateTime), 1200.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblExpense] ([Date], [Expense]) VALUES (CAST(0x00009FF300000000 AS DateTime), 1000.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[tblExpense] ([Date], [Expense]) VALUES (CAST(0x0000A01500000000 AS DateTime), 2000.0000)



SELECT  MonthName ,
        SUM(Income) ,
        SUM(Expense)
FROM    ( SELECT    MonthName ,
                    i.Income ,
                    NULL AS Expense
          FROM      dbo.Calendar c
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblIncome i ON c.StartdateInclusive <= i.Date
                                                 AND i.Date < c.enddateExclusive
          UNION
          SELECT    MonthName ,
                    NULL ,
                    e.Expense AS Expense
          FROM      dbo.Calendar c
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblExpense e ON c.StartdateInclusive <= e.Date
                                                  AND e.Date < c.enddateExclusive
        ) AS d
GROUP BY MonthName
```

Comment: actually i need a stored procedure to get the result

Comment: @suan There is no challenge in converting that query to a stored procedure. Did you search who to create a stored procedure in SQL Server?